# How to write for each statement in jstl?

Tags: jsp, jstl

How do I write a jstl foreach statement for a condition check greater than or equal to 5.

I know only `<c:forEach begin="0" end="5" varStatus="loop">`
but I don't know how to write greater than or equal with jsp.

I want to get it with jstl code  `for(i=0 ;i<= 5 ;i++)` 
please anyone help me to write back with jstl.Thanks alot.

Comment: You cannot add the `=` sign like in a Java `for` loop. Use `end="6"` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
<c:forEach varStatus="loop">
  <c:if test="${loop.index >=0 && loop.index <=5}">
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```